# how to find exact number from url parameters inside td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, url-parameters

I have got a problem. I am unable to find exact numbers from the td element. If I put down number 25 to search, it also finds number 2 and 5 separately inside the td element. I just want it to find 25. Same with if i find number 10, it also highlights number 1.

Here's the JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mxcw0Lbr/

Here's the code: HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>30</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
var search = "?" + [
"number=" + encodeURIComponent("25") ];

$('td').filter(function() {
  return search.indexOf(parseInt($(this).text(), 10)) != -1;
}).addClass('active');
```

CSS:

```
td {
color: #fff;
}

.picked {
color: #000;
}

.active {
color: #f30;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return parseInt($(this).text()) == 25;` works. So the problem is with your `search` variable value.

Comment: thank you for the answer@JPHellemons, it worked for me. You were right about the search, I managed to fix it. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to do it

For each td, you check if it corresponds to the `called` int value. This way, not matter what the called variable will be equal to in the URL it'll directly have it checked.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mxcw0Lbr/3/

```js
var search = "?" + [
  "called=" + decodeURIComponent("25")
  ].join("&");
  
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == search.match(/called=(\d+)/)[1];
}).addClass('active');
```

```css
td {
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0px 5.4px;
 line-height: 42px;
}

.picked {
 color: #000;
}

.active {
 color: #f30;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>29</td>
<td>30</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you bro for the detailed answer. It resolved my issue and made me understand the issue with my code. Thanks and have a great day :)

Comment: @pv619 happy to help ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you put down number 25 to search, it also finds number 2 and 5 separately inside the `td` element. This is because the `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array. Hence the call back in `filter` will returns true even if `td` has `2` only. Else it returns or `-1`. If you just want it to find 25, you can do as following

```
let $td=$('td');
$.each($td,function(){
  let $this=$(this)
  $this.toggleClass('active',$this.text()=='25');
});
```

OR

`$("td:contains('10')").addClass('active');` if you want less code

Comment: thank you soo much @Elish for the detailed explanation. I see due to the `indexOf` it was filtering everything within search criteria. Thank you once again for your help :) Have a great day :)